# Python regex -- extraneous matchings

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string using `-`, `+=`, `==`, `=`, `+`, and white-space as delimiters. I want to keep the delimiter unless it is white-space.

I've tried to achieve this with the following code:

```
def tokenize(s):
  import re
  pattern = re.compile("(\-|\+\=|\=\=|\=|\+)|\s+")
  return pattern.split(s)

print(tokenize("hello-+==== =+  there"))
```

I expected the output to be

```
['hello', '-', '+=', '==', '=', '=', '+', 'there']
```

However I got

```
['hello', '-', '', '+=', '', '==', '', '=', '', None, '', '=', '', '+', '', None, 'there']
```

Which is almost what I wanted, except that there are quite a few extraneous `None`s and empty strings.

Why is it behaving this way, and how might I change it to get what I want?

Comment: The empty strings are because you have 2 matching characters right next to each other, so when split apart they have an `''` in between them. It's a bit unintuitive with capture groups in the mix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[re.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) by default returns an array of the bits of strings that are in between the matches:  (As @Laurence Gonsalves notes, this is its main use.)

```
['hello', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'there']
```

Note the empty strings in between `-` and `+=`, `+=` and `==`, etc.

As the docs explain, because you're using a capture group (i.e., because you're using `(\-|\+\=|\=\=|\=|\+)` instead of `(?:\-|\+\=|\=\=|\=|\+)`, the bits that the capture group matches are interspersed:

```
['hello', '-', '', '+=', '', '==', '', '=', '', None, '', '=', '', '+', '', None, 'there']
```

`None` corresponds to where the `\s+` half of your pattern was matched; in those cases, the capture group captured nothing.

From looking at the docs for re.split, I don't see an easy way to have it discard empty strings in between matches, although a simple list comprehension (or [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), if you prefer) can easily discard `None`s and empty strings:

```
def tokenize(s):
  import re
  pattern = re.compile("(\-|\+\=|\=\=|\=|\+)|\s+")
  return [ x for x in pattern.split(s) if x ]
```

**One last note**:  For what you've described so far, this will work fine, but depending on the direction your project goes, you may want to switch to a proper parsing library.  [The Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) has a good overview of some of the options here.

Comment: Note that returning the in-between bits is sort of the "main behavior", analogous to str.split. The capturing thing is sort of an extra feature.

Answer (score 2):

*Why is it behaving this way?*

According to the documentation for re.split:

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

This is literally correct: if capturing parentheses are used, then the text of all groups are returned, whether or not they matched anything; the ones which didn't match anything return `None`.

As always with `split`, two consecutive delimiters are considered to separate empty strings, so you get empty strings interspersed.

*how might I change it to get what I want?*

The simplest solution is to filter the output:

```
filter(None, pattern.split(s))
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `re.findall` would be more suitable for you?

```
>>> re.findall(r'-|\+=|==|=|\+|[^-+=\s]+', "hello-+==== =+  there")
['hello', '-', '+=', '==', '=', '=', '+', 'there']
```

Comment: One concern I have with your solution is that later on I want to support more delimiters (e.g. `*`, `&&`), and I'm afraid that the `[^-+=\s]+` part of the pattern will get more complicated.

Comment: Are there any rules about the tokens that are not delimiters? Maybe you could use eg. `\w+` instead of `[^-+=\s]+`.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is more in line with what you want:

```
\s*(\-|\+\=|\=\=|\=|\+)\s*
```

You will still get an empty string between each split, though, as you should expect.

Comment: That won't break "Hello there" into two tokens, which I believe is OP's intent with using whitespace as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def tokenize(s):
  import re
  pattern = re.compile("(\-|\+\=|\=\=|\=|\+)|\s+")
  x = pattern.split(s)
  result = []
  for item in x:
    if item != '' and item != None:
      result.append(item)
  return result

print(tokenize("hello-+==== =+  there"))
```